# CodeBuild: docker push to another regions timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-codebuild

Current build specification pulls test containers and base image for docker build.
The docker push to ECR works as long as the push is to the same region as the build.

Even though I successfully log into another ECR region, the docker push fails to push to a region other than the build region.

Summary:

- Build in us-east-1 and push to us-east-1 ECR is successful.
- Build in us-east-1 and push to us-west-1 ECR fails.

Therefore, I don't believe this to be a permissions issue since the IAM Role is global.

buildspec.yml

```
version: 0.2

env:
  variables:
    APP_NAME: "config-server"
    ARTIFACT_REPO: "config-server"
    ARTIFACT_DOMAIN: "osint"
    ACCOUNT_ID: "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
    BUILD_REGION: "us-east-1"
    ECR_BUILD_REPO: xxxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
  exported-variables:
    - CODEBUILD_BUILD_NUMBER
    - CODEBUILD_BUILD_ID
phases:
  install:
    on-failure: ABORT
    commands:
      - echo "Building software in ${BUILD_REGION}. Publishing images to ${ECR_PUSH_REGION} @ ${ECR_PUSH_REPO}"
      - java --version
      - aws --version
      - mvn --version
    finally:
      - echo "Installation complete"
  pre_build:
    on-failure: ABORT
    commands:
      - echo "Begin pre-build ${CODEBUILD_BUILD_ID}"
      - echo "Configure Code Artifact ${ARTIFACT_REPO}"
      - cp pipeline/settings.xml ~/.m2
      - echo "Configure ECR"
      - aws ecr get-login-password --region ${BUILD_REGION} | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin ${ACCOUNT_ID}.dkr.ecr.${BUILD_REGION}.amazonaws.com
      - docker pull ${ECR_BUILD_REPO}/eclipse-temurin:17-jre-alpine
      - echo "Done pulling images"
  build:
    on-failure: ABORT
    commands:
      - echo "Build started ${CODEBUILD_BUILD_ID}"
      - export CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN=`aws codeartifact get-authorization-token --domain ${ARTIFACT_DOMAIN} --domain-owner ${ACCOUNT_ID} --region ${BUILD_REGION} --query authorizationToken --output text`
      - mvn package deploy --no-transfer-progress
      - echo "DONE PACKAGE TARGET; `ls -l target`"
      - echo Building the Docker image...
      - version=`mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q -DforceStdout`
      - if [[ ${version} = *'SNAPSHOT'* ]]; then version="${version:0:3}";  fi
      - export IMAGE_TAG=${ECR_PUSH_REPO}/${APP_NAME}:${version}.${CODEBUILD_BUILD_NUMBER}
      - echo "IMAGE TAG=${IMAGE_TAG}"
      - docker build . -t ${IMAGE_TAG} -f pipeline/Dockerfile
    finally:
      - echo "Build complete"
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo "Post Build started ${CODEBUILD_BUILD_ID}"
      - echo PUBLISHING IMAGES....
      - docker images
      - aws ecr get-login-password --region ${ECR_PUSH_REGION} | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin ${ACCOUNT_ID}.dkr.ecr.${ECR_PUSH_REGION}.amazonaws.com
      - echo "Logged on to ${ECR_PUSH_REGION} pushing to ${IMAGE_TAG}"
      - docker push ${IMAGE_TAG}
    finally:
      - echo "Post Build completed"
```

logs:

```
[Container] 2024/01/03 19:04:56.476682 Running command export IMAGE_TAG=${ECR_PUSH_REPO}/${APP_NAME}:${version}.${CODEBUILD_BUILD_NUMBER}

[Container] 2024/01/03 19:04:56.483331 Running command echo "IMAGE TAG=${IMAGE_TAG}"
IMAGE TAG=xxxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/config-server/config-server:1.0.23

[Container] 2024/01/03 19:04:56.489977 Running command docker build . -t ${IMAGE_TAG} -f pipeline/Dockerfile
#0 building with "default" instance using docker driver

#1 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
#1 transferring dockerfile: 1.25kB done
#1 DONE 0.0s

#2 [internal] load .dockerignore
#2 transferring context: 2B done
#2 DONE 0.0s

#3 [internal] load metadata for xxxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/eclipse-temurin:17-jre-alpine
#3 DONE 0.0s

#4 [ 1/14] FROM xxxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/eclipse-temurin:17-jre-alpine
#4 DONE 0.1s

#5 [internal] load build context
#5 transferring context: 73.22MB 0.5s done
#5 DONE 0.5s

#6 [ 2/14] RUN apk update &&     apk add --no-cache shadow &&     apk add --no-cache bash  &&     apk add openssh
#6 0.387 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.18/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
#6 0.468 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.18/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
#6 0.676 v3.18.5-87-g543300ec707 [https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.18/main]
#6 0.676 v3.18.5-88-gdfacf7fe602 [https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.18/community]
#6 0.676 OK: 20070 distinct packages available
#6 0.716 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.18/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
#6 0.786 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.18/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
#6 0.973 (1/2) Installing linux-pam (1.5.2-r10)
#6 0.986 (2/2) Installing shadow (4.13-r4)
#6 1.002 Executing busybox-1.36.1-r5.trigger
#6 1.006 OK: 42 MiB in 46 packages
#6 1.055 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.18/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
#6 1.135 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.18/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
#6 1.334 OK: 42 MiB in 46 packages
#6 1.581 (1/8) Installing openssh-keygen (9.3_p2-r1)
#6 1.625 (2/8) Installing libedit (20221030.3.1-r1)
#6 1.629 (3/8) Installing openssh-client-common (9.3_p2-r1)
#6 1.652 (4/8) Installing openssh-client-default (9.3_p2-r1)
#6 1.663 (5/8) Installing openssh-sftp-server (9.3_p2-r1)
#6 1.667 (6/8) Installing openssh-server-common (9.3_p2-r1)
#6 1.669 (7/8) Installing openssh-server (9.3_p2-r1)
#6 1.679 (8/8) Installing openssh (9.3_p2-r1)
#6 1.685 Executing busybox-1.36.1-r5.trigger
#6 1.689 OK: 48 MiB in 54 packages
#6 DONE 2.6s

#12 [ 8/14] COPY pipeline/scripts/startServer.sh /opt/config-server/scripts
#12 DONE 0.1s

#13 [ 9/14] RUN chmod 770 /opt/config-server/scripts/startServer.sh
#13 DONE 0.5s

#14 [10/14] RUN mkdir -p /opt/config-server/config
#14 DONE 0.4s

#15 exporting to image
#15 exporting layers
#15 exporting layers 0.4s done
#15 writing image sha256:1cf6188ef7455bc5666a5b08c4dcf67e58599c47249c56ac02c560e44c7df29c done
#15 naming to xxxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/config-server/config-server:1.0.23 done
#15 DONE 0.4s

[Container] 2024/01/03 19:05:04.821650 Running command echo "Build complete"
Build complete

[Container] 2024/01/03 19:05:04.835218 Phase complete: BUILD State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2024/01/03 19:05:04.835234 Phase context status code:  Message: 
[Container] 2024/01/03 19:05:04.870408 Entering phase POST_BUILD

[Container] 2024/01/03 19:05:04.877788 Running command echo PUBLISHING IMAGES....
PUBLISHING IMAGES....

[Container] 2024/01/03 19:05:04.885122 Running command docker images
REPOSITORY                                                                                                     TAG                           IMAGE ID       CREATED                  SIZE
xxxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/config-server/config-server                                       1.0.23                        1cf6188ef745   Less than a second ago   334MB

[Container] 2024/01/03 19:05:04.911478 Running command aws ecr get-login-password --region ${ECR_PUSH_REGION} | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin ${ACCOUNT_ID}.dkr.ecr.${ECR_PUSH_REGION}.amazonaws.com
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /root/.docker/config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store

Login Succeeded

[Container] 2024/01/03 19:05:06.256340 Running command echo "Logged on to ${ECR_PUSH_REGION} pushing to ${IMAGE_TAG}"
Logged on to us-west-1 pushing to xxxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/config-server/config-server:1.0.23

[Container] 2024/01/03 19:05:06.263693 Running command docker push ${IMAGE_TAG}
The push refers to repository [xxxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/config-server/config-server]
57936ee548d0: Preparing
ea843b68ef0d: Preparing
ea843b68ef0d: Retrying in 1 second
322f6000e4aa: Retrying in 1 second
EOF

[Container] 2024/01/03 19:05:57.948539 Command did not exit successfully docker push ${IMAGE_TAG} exit status 1
[Container] 2024/01/03 19:05:57.953478 Running command echo "Post Build completed"
Post Build completed

[Container] 2024/01/03 19:05:57.965838 Phase complete: POST_BUILD State: FAILED
[Container] 2024/01/03 19:05:57.965855 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: docker push ${IMAGE_TAG}. Reason: exit status 1
```

Comment: I think the problem is with your IMAGE_TAG variable, what is the value of the ECR_PUSH_REPO variable?

Comment: IMAGE TAG=xxxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/config-server/config-server:1.0.23
BUILD: #15 naming to xxxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/config-server/config-server:1.0.23 done                                                                                      The push refers to repository [xxxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/config-server/config-server]  NOTE: us-west-1